# How to specify compiler for "gem install"?

Tags: rubygems

How can I specify which compiler should be used for `gem install`? In Bash

```
CC=gcc gem install ...
```

does not help, because it still uses Solaris Studio on my system.

Comment: forgot to mention, it is the sqlite3-ruby -v1.2.5 gem

Answer (score 11):

For sqlite3-ruby your method is supported since Jan 2011 commit. But in general
it's not possible to override this because of how rubygems works. It

1. Unpacks the gem.
2. Looks into it spec & discovers that it uses 'extensions' attribute--usually a
   path to a specially written extconf.rb file.
3. Runs that file to generate a Makefile. Unless author of extconf.rb explicitly
   said to honor env variables, they are ignored. For example, in latest
   versions of sqlite3-ruby gem, its extconf.rb has a line

   ```rb
   RbConfig::MAKEFILE_CONFIG['CC'] = ENV['CC'] if ENV['CC']
   ```

   So if you run in Bash

   ```
   CC=gcc gem install sqlite3-ruby
   ```

   extconf.rb will generate the Makefile with the variable `CC` in it that is
   set to `gcc` or whatever you want.
4. After Makefile is generated, rubygems executes `make` utility to compile the
   extension.

Theoretically, if rubygems allowed us to specify additional command line
parameters for make, we could use its `-e` option and then do not depend on
authors of extconf.rb at all.
(`-e` option gives variables taken from the environment precedence over
variables from makefiles.)

Answer (score 5):

Using RVM, on OS X, I change the following file to achieve a permanent change of the gcc compiler:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.X.Y/lib/ruby/1.X/i686-darwin10.8.0/rbconfig.rb
```

In this file I found the following:

```
  CONFIG["configure_args"] = " ...' 'CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2'"

  CONFIG["CC"] = "/usr/bin/gcc-4.2"

  CONFIG["CPP"] = "/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -E"
```

I no longer have this gcc-4.2 compiles on my box, only /usr/bin/gcc. Replacing gcc-4.2 by gcc worked ok for installing an old gem. This is while I'm being cornered working in an old environment I can't upgrade.